# MSBuild command line execution of Visual Studio 2010 Solution fails referencing VS2010 SDK to build an extension

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, msbuild, visual-studio-extensions

#### Scenario

- Solution that has a VS2010 extension in it (.NET 4 Class library, with a WPF UI)
- It builds fine inside visual studio
- On the **same machine** when I attempt to build it via command line (as part of a build script)
- **Fails** when using this command to attempt to build it:

  - `msbuild JsExt.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:OutDir=..\..\Binaries`
- **Update**

  - To `MSBuild` Adding `/property:VsSDKInstall="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\VSSDK"` leads to this exception...

#### Exception

> The "VSCTCompiler" task failed unexpectedly.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.Common.targets(74,5): error MSB4018:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

#### Extra info

1. Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1 is installed
2. The path to and file `Microsoft.VsSDK.Common.targets` does exist.
3. I'm running from an `x86` console and PowerShell window and `vcvarsall.bat (x86)` are loaded
4. I'm not sure what the `tmp_proj` is about.
5. It's a WPF User Interface, is there something I'm missing to compile something with WPF/XAML via MSBuild?
6. There is nothing pre/post build events of the CSProj file that is the extension.
7. Build platform target is `Any CPU`
8. I have other solutions/projects working well with the same `MSBuild` command.
9. Setting `/v:diag` doesn't offer much more information on the errors.

Any ideas, what am I missing, what's next to debug?

Comment: Are you calling: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86' in your build script?

Comment: @DaveShaw yes, they are loaded, confirmed by running it explicitly before executing the build command, still fails with same exceptions

Comment: Sorry then, that was my only idea

Answer (score 2):

Is the VSSDKInstall env variable set / showing up in your console?

```
VSSDK100Install=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1\
```

If so, then add "/v:diag" to your cmd line to see what that turns up.

Take a look at the following [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronmar/archive/2011/05/10/visual-studio-extensions-and-build-servers.aspx) - step #3 sounds like your original issue, and step #4 explains the subsequent VSCTCompiler issue that you just encountered.

Comment: It wasn't but I supply it via the msbuild command variables, I'll update the question, as now there's another error showing up - `The "VSCTCompiler" task failed unexpectedly.`

Comment: Apparently some VSSDK tasks still require the VsSDKInstall path to be set as environment variable.