# MsBuild with Visual Studio 2012 Package Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-package

I have created .NET solution with **Visual Studio 2012 Package** Project (From **VS2012 SDK**). With Visual Studio I successfully compile and run this project (along with entire solution) in "**Debug**" configuration mode, and for "**Any CPU**" platform. But when I try to build solution in command line using **MsBuild**, I get errors:

**Command:**

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

**Errors:**

**error : Can not find the installation for VS SDK.**
**error MSB4018: The "FindVsSDKInstallation" task fail
ed unexpectedly.**
**error MSB4018: System.ArgumentNullException: Value can
not be null.**
 **error MSB4018: Parameter name: path1**
**error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String pat
h1, String path2)**
**error MSB4028: The "FindVsSDKInstallation" task's ou
tputs could not be retrieved from the "IncludesPath" parameter. Value cannot be
 null.**
**error MSB4028: Parameter name: path1**

All activities are performed on my local Windows 7, with VS2012 and SDK installed.

I was looking for solution on the Web and I have found the following topic: [FindVsSDKInstallation task fails on the build box](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1cdab25b-1a8d-46c9-a9bc-24c100887d4a/findvssdkinstallation-task-fails-on-the-build-box). There is said that such a project should be compiled for **"x86"** platform, because `devenv.exe` process is 32-bit. So I change a `Platform Target` property from Project Properties to **"x86"** (for **"Debug"** mode). The result is the same - project is built successfully in VS but not in `MsBuild`.

Why VS2012 Package project is properly built by using VS, but `MsBuild` fails? How should I run `MsBuild` to build it successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use a visual studio command prompt, or call the vsvars batch file e.g. 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

Second, the link you gave also says

> "I think setting the "VsSDKInstall" environment variable should work
>   too"

There's a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583564/msbuild-command-line-execution-of-visual-studio-2010-solution-fails-referencing)